# error: cast from 'Foo*' to 'unsigned int' loses precision

Tags: c++, casting, intptr

I'm trying to cast a pointer to an int (or unsigned int) and no matter what I try it doesn't want to work.

I've tried `static_cast<intptr_t>(obj)`, `reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(obj)`, and various combinations of C style casts, `intptr_t`'s, `unsigned int`'s, and I'm including stdint.h. From what I've read, one of the many things I've tried should work. What gives?

I didn't bother including the code because it's exactly what I described, but since you asked, I've tried all of these plus other combinations:

```
void myfunc(Foo* obj)
{
    // ...
    uintptr_t temp = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(obj);
    uintptr_t temp = static_cast<uintptr_t>(obj);
    uintptr_t temp = (uintptr_t)obj;
    intptr_t temp = reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(obj);
    intptr_t temp = static_cast<intptr_t>(obj);
    intptr_t temp = (intptr_t)obj;
    unsigned int temp = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(obj);
    unsigned int temp = static_cast<unsigned int>(obj);
    unsigned int temp = (unsigned int)obj;
    // ...
}
```

They all give the exact same error.

Comment: What are you casting for? Tell us the problem not the step.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Also, include the problem code.

Comment: $ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5659)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: Try option `-fpermissive`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're either on a platform where `sizeof (Foo*) > sizeof (unsigned)`, or your compiler is set to warn about non-portable code.  Note that most 64-bit compilers, both LP64 and LLP64, fall into this category.

There's no requirement that a pointer fit in an `int`.  That's the whole point of `intptr_t`.

If you're using a third-party library that provides only a `int` for user-context during callbacls, you could pass an index into a lookup table, so the pointer itself is stored in the lookup table.  This has the additional benefit of being type-safe and not breaking aliasing assumptions.

EDIT: Works for me.  ([Comeau "tryitout"](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) is very handy)

```
#include <stdint.h>

void myfunc(class Foo* obj)
{
    uintptr_t temp = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(obj);
}
```

> Comeau C/C++ 4.3.10.1 (Oct  6 2008
>   11:28:09) for ONLINE_EVALUATION_BETA2
>   Copyright 1988-2008 Comeau Computing. 
>   All rights reserved. MODE:strict
>   errors C++ C++0x_extensions
>
> "ComeauTest.c", line 5: warning:
>   variable "temp" was declared but never
>   referenced
>         uintptr_t temp = reinterpret_cast(obj);reinterpret_cast(obj);
>
> In strict mode, with -tused, Compile succeeded (but remember, the Comeau online compiler does not link). 
>   Compiled with C++0x extensions enabled.

In C89 mode it also works:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void myfunc(struct Foo* obj)
{
    uintptr_t temp = (uintptr_t)obj;
}
```

> Comeau C/C++ 4.3.10.1 (Oct  6 2008
>   11:28:09) for ONLINE_EVALUATION_BETA2
>   Copyright 1988-2008 Comeau Computing. 
>   All rights reserved. MODE:strict
>   errors C90
>
> "ComeauTest.c", line 3: warning:
>   declaration is not visible outside of
>   function   void myfunc(struct Foo*
>   obj)
>                        ^
>
> "ComeauTest.c", line 5: warning:
>   variable "temp" was declared but never
>   referenced
>         uintptr_t temp = (uintptr_t)obj;
>                   ^
>
> In strict mode, with -tused, Compile
>   succeeded (but remember, the Comeau
>   online compiler does not link).

Comment: Right, and I've tried intptr_t, and I still get errors. `intptr_t test = reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(obj)` does not work.

Comment: So turns out I'm an idiot :P I had a second instance of this somewhere else in my file that I had forgotten about (this compiles fine btw on my other computer). I kept seeing error messages even after getting it right, but they were now pointing at the other instance of me doing incorrect casting, and I hadn't noticed the change in line number. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it is better to master the type conversion by explicit cast. And the previous answers say it well.

But I have a suggestion to bypass the compiler. There is an option to let the compiler accept the current loss of precision:

```
gcc -fpermissive
```