# How to convert custom class pointer to unsigned int

Tags: c++, casting

I need to type cast custom class pointer to unsigned int value. Here is what I tired.

```
Class A{
};

int main()
{
A* a = foo();
unsigned int handler = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(a);
return 0;
}
```

It gives the warning
`warning C4302: 'reinterpret_cast': truncation from 'A *' to 'unsigned int'`

What it the proper way to overcome this in C++ way

Comment: Looks pretty similar to [the first related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898158/error-cast-from-foo-to-unsigned-int-loses-precision?rq=1)

Comment: Likely you're on a 64 bit platform.  unsigned int isn't big enough to hold a 64 bit pointer.

Comment: Why do you want to convert a pointer to an integer in the first place? That's rarely a useful thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error may imply that you're compiling to a 64 bit target, in which case a pointer a 64 bit, which reinterpret_cast'd to int means truncation (because int is atmost 32 bit).

Not sure what you're going to do with the handler, but the safer way is to cast to uintptr_t if c++11 is available.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

With `<cstdint>` included, it should be something like,

```
uintptr_t handler = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(a);
```

Comment: ya you are right, I'm building to 64bit. how to achieve it by  `uintptr_t`? I have C++11 environment

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya uintptr_t is defined in <cstdint>, once you have the include, then just go like, 

    uintptr_t handler = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(a);

Comment: @techolic: Actually, `::uintptr_t` is defined in `stdint.h`.  With `#include <cstdint>` you're only guaranteed to have `std::uintptr_t`

Comment: you are right techolic. Please add your comment to the answer. So it will be clear. tnx!